# POCO C++ Libs Scalability

Tags: c++, sockets, web, scaling, poco-libraries

We have an application which is written primarily using poco, it uses web sockets and at the moment we have heard a number of 40/50,000 clients per server range of connected clients, I however now am starting to question pocos scaling capability where nodejs and others can do up to 1 Million users on a single machine. SO I first have to ask, can poco handle this traffic? I have 10 Million + devices.... i dont want to deploy 300 servers on the front end to scale poco to handle the traffic... is there a known bottleneck ?

Comment: What kind of POCOs? Need a **lot** more details to answer a question like this.

Comment: meaning the poco c++ library

Comment: Then, as the tag wiki says, please edit the question to use the 'poco-libraries' tag.

Comment: I think unless the company has performance data you should "simply" test it (and even then, probably). Sounds as if (1) the library is doing a mission critical job and (2) your company has some resources. You should use some of these resources to test the mission critical parts.